# Avoid using Uppercase in Class and ID in CSS

Tags: css

CSS is **insensitive** for **id** and **class**, am curious like to know why i was advised not to use any uppercase to the id and class.

Just to clarify, I am referring to

```
.table_Row or #table_Row or #Table_Row
```

Also look up to Element and attribute names and attribute values
[result case](https://www.w3.org/International/tests/html-css/selectors-case/results-selectors-case)

Comment: Who says it's not recommended? Do you have a link?  It's certainly good practice to use the same case in all places (for find/replace, readability etc.)

Comment: I've been using uppercase classes with the bem101 methology for years now, never had any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no reason for uppercase letters. In *programming* languages (for example JavaScript) you *need* a reliable way to distinguish functions, variables, constants, classes, etc.

So, one would write variables in UpperCamelCase, functions in lowerCamelCase, constants in UPPERCASE and so on.

HTML is much simpler, and so, there is no need to type "ID" or "Class". Lesser keystrokes and more accurate visual view.

Also, what about `href`, for example? How would you write it? `HRef`? I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: what i meant was e.g. #table_Row  or .table_Row

Comment: @JOng This is very strange naming convention. There are no official restrictions, but nobody use it, because it looks ugly and because it goes in contradiction with the generally accepted practices. Usually people use `#table_row` (snake_case) or `#table-row` (lisp-case). Much ralely - `#tableRow` (lowerCamelCase) or `#TableRow` (UpperCamelCase).

Comment: @JOng By the way, sometimes, it could be useful. For example, when you have very complex structure of classes. So, the naming like `#FaaFoo_BarBaz` could make sence. You could take a look at structure of classes in Twitter Bootstrap. It uses lisp-case (lowercase letters delimited with hyphen), but it's classes structure is really such complex as I described. If it answers your question, don't forgot to click "check mark" on the left side of my answer :-)

Comment: I will definitely take note of that! Thank you for answering my queries.

Comment: @ncode Take a look also at this: https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/. It shows the same idea. So, class names could be something like `.BigButton_Price` and `.BigButton-Red` (see the examples at the beginning of the article).